# AsyncTask Android nullpointexception when i run the app

Tags: java, php, android, android-asynctask

Am a newbie with no adequate info how to resolve this. any expertise here would be helpful.

nullpointexception when i run the app. With nothing showing inside their views

Thats my PHP script:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["image_name"] = $row["image_name"];
    $product["image_type"] = $row["image_type"];


    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

My mainactivity with async task:

```
public class SimpleGridPatternViewActivity extends BaseActivity {
String url = "http://192.168.0.23/giveaways/tickets.php";
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_grid_pattern_view);

    final GridPatternView<BaseAdapter> gridPatternView = (GridPatternView<BaseAdapter>) findViewById(R.id.parchment_view);

    final List<GridPatternItemDefinition> gridPatternItemDefinitions = new ArrayList<GridPatternItemDefinition>();

    FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask();

    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(0, 0, 6, 4));
    gridPatternView
            .addGridPatternGroupDefinition(gridPatternItemDefinitions);
    gridPatternItemDefinitions.clear();

    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(0, 0, 2, 2));
    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(2, 0, 2, 2));
    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(4, 0, 2, 3));
    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(0, 2, 4, 4));
    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(4, 3, 2, 3));
    gridPatternView
            .addGridPatternGroupDefinition(gridPatternItemDefinitions);
    gridPatternItemDefinitions.clear();

    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(0, 0, 2, 3));
    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(2, 0, 4, 4));
    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(0, 3, 2, 3));
    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(2, 4, 2, 2));
    gridPatternItemDefinitions
            .add(new GridPatternItemDefinition(4, 4, 2, 2));
    gridPatternView
            .addGridPatternGroupDefinition(gridPatternItemDefinitions);

    task.execute(url);

    gridPatternView.setAdapter(getProductsAdapter());

}

@Override
public int getLayoutResourceId() {
    return R.layout.list_item_gridpatternview_picture;
}

class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String msg;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (params == null)
            return null;

        // get url from params
        String url = params[0];

        try {
            // create http connection
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            // connect
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);

            // get response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity == null) {
                msg = "No response from server";
                return null;
            }

            // get response content and convert it to json string
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return streamToString(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg = "No Network Connection";
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String arg0) {

        try {
            // convert json string to json array
            JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(products);
            // create apps list
            List<Model> mModels = new ArrayList<Model>();

            for (int i = 0; i < aJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                Model mdl = new Model();
                mdl.setImage(json.getString("image_name"));
                mdl.setType(json.getString("image_type"));

                // add the app to apps list
                mModels.add(mdl);
            }

            // notify the activity that fetch data has been complete

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            msg = "Invalid response";

            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function will convert response stream into json string
     * 
     * @param is
     *            respons string
     * @return json string
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String streamToString(final InputStream is) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

}

And my adapter:

```
 public class ProductsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final int mLayoutResourceId;

public ProductsAdapter(final int layoutResourceId) {
    super();
    mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;

}

private List<Model> mModels = new ArrayList<Model>();

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mModels.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(final int position) {
    return mModels.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(final int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

private View getView(final Context context, final View convertView,
        final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId,
                viewGroup, false);
        return view;
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {
    final Context context = parent.getContext();
    final View view = getView(context, convertView, parent);

    Model model = (Model) getItem(position);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.list_item_picture_image_view);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    Picasso.with(context).load(model.getmUrl()).into(imageView);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.list_item_picture_text_view);
    textView.setText(model.getImage());
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: It will help someone to answer if you add a specific question.

Comment: Thanks @Val Asensio.. The question there...With the above scripts theres a nullpointexception when i run the app. With nothing showing inside their views.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to add the text from your comment above to the first paragraph of your question. If people don't see the question up there, they may not come down to read the comments.

Comment: @Val Asensio the question has been added. Any expertise offered will go a long way